# Find method by AccessFlags

Tags: javassist

I want to search `declared methods` by flags and other informations.

For example, i want to search the Method `public final void ae(StringTokenizer);`.

Here is a sample method, how i want to search it:

```
private CtMethod findMethod(CtClass clazz, int access, String returns, String[] parameters) throws NotFoundException {

    /*
       returns = null = void, other String for returned class name
       parameters = easy names of parameters
    */
    CtMethod found = null;

    for(CtMethod method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      // Check here all flags and informations - If found, set the `found` variable and return
    }

    return found;
 }
```

Here is a sample call:

```
 CtMethod inputMethod = this.findMethod(theClass, AccessFlag.FINAL, null, new String[] { "StringTokenizer" });
```

How i can check the explicit flags, for sample `AccessFlag.FINAL | AccessFlag.PUBLIC`?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the modifiers by calling `CtMethod::getModifiers​`. You can then check if the modifiers are set:

```
if (ctMethod.getModifiers() & (AccessFlag.FINAL | AccessFlag.PUBLIC) != 0) {
  found = ctMethod;
  break;
}
```